# using Python watchdog module to examine Sharepoint file changes

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, power-automate, watchdog

I am seeking to automate the processing of numeric and text data submitted by multiple colleagues on MS Forms which in turn goes through a Power Automate transfer to a .xlsx sheet housed on a MS Teams site.
I want to trigger a Python script to do a lot of heavy-lifting in terms of processing and distribution of data to other user groups.
I am using `Office365-REST-Python-Client 2.3.9` to extract the data held on Sharepoint/Teams, but would ideally like this to be automated, for example using Python's `Watchdog` module.
So, my question is, can the Python module Watchdog handle probe cloud-based files such as my Teams based .xlsx file.

Comment: Hi, did you happen to find an answer to your question?

Comment: No, sorry, no reply and I moved onto different approaches

Comment: which approach did you find?